# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox clicking or selecting an option from a select?

Tags: perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

How do you click or select an option in a `select` using `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`. The `select` is within a `form` in this case.

Code follows:

```
<form name="formo">
<select class="selectc" onchange="go()" name="selecto">
<option value="">Option 1</option>
<option value="">Option 2</option>
<option value="?place1">Option 3</option>
<option value="?place2">Option 4</option>
```

I would like to click Option 3 to go to place1, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `$mech->select` like this:

```
$mech->select( 'selecto', '?place1' );
```

The first parameter is the name of the `select` element, the second is the value you want to set it to. That value has to be one of the `option`s inside the `select`. See [the docs](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox#mech-select-name-value) for more info.

Comment: so the signiture: `$mech->select('name of select', 'value or name of option')`